# Celery update_state inside class method

Tags: python, flask, celery

I am new to celery and begin to understand how it works. However I have some trouble understanding how to update the state from inside the class method.

**views.py**

```
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def foo_bar():
    task = foo_async.apply_async()
    return json.dumps({}),202
```

**background_task.py**

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def foo_async(self):
    t = Test()
    t.run()
    return json.dumps({'progress':100})
```

**test.py**

```
class Test(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = 'bar'
    def run(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print 'Current : ',i
            self.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'current':i})
            time.sleep(4)
```

But I get this error after making a request :

```
[...] return task_id.replace('-','')  
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

So I see that the problem is regarding the **id** but I don't how to fix that.
Maybe there is a better way to get update from inside my method ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you call `self.update_state()` the `self` that you are using is the one for your class `Test`. You need to do that on the `self` that was given to you on the entry point of your task, the argument to function `foo_async`.

Is there any reason why you defined class `Test` as a subclass of `Task`? You already have a task, created by the `celery.task` decorator.

Try the following:

```
@celery.task(bind=True)
def foo_async(self):
    t = Test(self)
    t.run()
    return json.dumps({'progress':100})

class Test(object):
    def __init__(self, task):
        self.task = task
        self.foo = 'bar'
    def run(self):
        for i in range(0,10):
            print 'Current : ',i
            self.task.update_state(state='PROGRESS',meta={'current':i})
            time.sleep(4)
```